# rails bootstrap Javascript include doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I'm trying to put Bootstrap library in my rails application, I put the script css in Stylesheets, it's working fine, and the js file in Javascript folder, I have no error in the console, I added in my application.js:

```
//= require bootstrap.min
```

after the jquery include. I tried with the bootstrap not minimized too

I tried in the application:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip({
  animation: true,
  html : true,
 });
});
```

and in my html (haml syntax):

```
%a{"data-toggle" => "tooltip", :href => "#", :title => "first tooltip"} Test
```

But nothing works, do you have an idea?

thanks by advance for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to mark your HTML according to the javascript selector you use:

```
%a{:rel => "tooltip", :href => "#", :title => "first tooltip"} Test
```

Note the `rel` attribute, instead of `data-toogle`.

As a general rule, I'd also recommend using a broader selector: `$("[rel~=tooltip]")`, so you can use more than one `rel` value in the same element.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for the `$("[rel~=tooltip]")` it was usefull